# Keyboard shortcut for moving between tabs when there is a split?

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio, I rely on the shortcuts for moving between tabs, and added a shortcut to Move Right, which makes any open tab split from the rest. The only problem is, I'm not sure at this point how to move back to the tabs on the other side of the split without grabbing my mouse and clicking. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 65):

if you mean changing tabs for when there is a split:
you can go to `settings -> keymap -> main menu -> window -> editor tabs` and set a shortcut for `Goto Next Splitter` and `Goto Previuos Splitter`

if you mean moving between tabs with no split use these:

Linux: <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd> AND <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>right</kbd>

Windows: <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd> AND <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>right</kbd>

OSX: <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> AND <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>

Comment: Nice answer to a different question :p

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize it was called a splitter instead of a tab!

Comment: IMO, doing with mouse is faster than these shortcut keys. No Offense!!

Comment: you can change these shortcuts easily to whatever is easier.

Comment: Is it just me or is the OSX: cmd + shift + [ not working any more?

Comment: still working on my Mac. anyway you can check what your shortcuts are set to by going to : settings -> keymap -> main menu -> window -> Select Next/Previous Tab.

Comment: gt and gT also works as in vim and vimium

Answer (score 13):

In order to do this you need to add a shortcut that maps to `Goto Previous Splitter` and while you are at it you may as well add one for `Goto Next Splitter`.

[image: key mappings]

Comment: In my case, I was looking to move between tabs. The above works if you go to Keymap/Window/Editor Tabs/Select Next Tab

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, you can use the actions: "Goto Next Splitter" or "Goto Previous Splitter" which on the Mac OS X 10.5+ Keymap defaults to:

<kbd>⌥ (option)</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⇧Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>